# Email html template for Outlook 2010 vs Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, email, templates, outlook

Could anybody prove/confirm the statement that the same emails may look different in Outlook 2010 vs Outlook 2013 (so I'd better test it in both Outlooks).
The reason I'm asking is a building email html template with proper rules (using tables etc.) and testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 main flavors of Outlook:

- Outlook '07, '10 and '13 (MS Word Engine)
- Outlook '00, '02, '03, Express (IE Engine)
- Outlook '11 (Webkit)
- Outlook.com

As long as you test at least one in each bulletpoint, you should have all the bases covered for Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2013 is just like Outlook 2010. Microsoft still using the same Word rendering engine to display HTML email.

you are building an email; so I am guessing that you are worried about CSS support is same or not for the 2013 version.

In Outlook 2013 CSS support is identical to Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.

you can find some evidence from this [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3769/a-designers-guide-to-outlook-2013).